# Can I revert svn up when I have no local modifications?

Tags: svn

Suppose I download a svn repository. After a couple of days I do `svn up FILE` to align with a new revision `X`. Again, after a couple of days I do `svn up FILE` since there was an update. Can I revert the state to the intermediate revision `X`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
But the way to do it depends on what you need:

- **If you don't need to commit the modifications**, you have to perform an "update" of your local file to the revision X:

  ```
  svn update -rX FILE
  ```

  In this case you will not be able to commit, because your svn client will not detect any modification between your local copy and the revision X. Before any next commit of local modifications, you will have to perform a `svn update FILE` (`-rHEAD` being implicit if not present) to update to the HEAD revision.
- **If you need to commit the modifications**, you have to perform a reverse merge of the modifications committed since the revision X, as follows:

  ```
  svn merge -rHEAD:X FILE
  ```

  In this case you will be able to commit, because your svn client will detect modifications between the local copy and the revision on which you performed the last update.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I don't know the number X. Does svn keep track of it? I think that I could revert both up's with svn info, but I don't know if a single one is possible.

Comment: Well you can run `svn log` to see the history of revisions of the file.